# Change value at Onchange event without an ID

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I have this problem. I'm trying to automate a powershell script that changes an onchange event on a website. I have to do this to scape the table afterwards.
The problem is that the onchange does not have an ID to select it.
Is it possible to do.?

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <select onchange="update_usage(this)">
      <option selected="selected"value="/Licenses/UserUsageLast24Hours/">Last 24 hours</option>
      <option value="/Licenses/UserUsageLast7Days/">Last 7 days</option>
      <option value="/Licenses/UserUsageLast30Days">Last 30 days</option>
   </select>
</div>
```